# Steam tray icon does not work properly

Tags: steam, taskbar

On Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit the Steam tray icon on the upper right task bar not working as it should. I tried installing steam as a Debian package and through `apt` but the issue still persists. Also this issue was not present in 14.04.5 LTS 64-bit. What may be the cause of this(missing libraries)?

```
~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

Comment: Can you open steam using the terminal `steam`?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working as it should? It doesn't show up? or it doesn't open the menu when clicked? What?

Comment: @barotto It does not show the menu, the only thing I get is an empty rectangle.

Comment: @M.Becerra I am adding the command line output.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4795) your problem? There's a screenshot by user tatokis that seems like what you describe.

Comment: @barotto Exactly like that thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @barotto Problem is solved thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by a missing 32-bit library on 64-bit installation and the command that solved the issue was:
`sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-glib4:i386`

The solution is included in this [link](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4795), thanks barotto for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

In my case with Ubuntu 16.04 it was `sudo apt install libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386`. So try it if @Vesnog's answer doesn't fix your problem.